# Pie chart avoiding same adjacent color when rotating colors

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

To rotate say 5 colors, ABCDE
4 slices: ABCD
5 slices: ABCDE
7 slices: ABCDEAB
6 slices: ABCDEA
DaDa! The two A's are adjacent.

How to avoid this?
I am okay switching to
6 slices: ABCDEB  or whatever, color sequence does not matter
but how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many ways of doing this. One of the simplest is to have multiple color sets (with different number of colors)... and depending on the number of data items (sectors in pie), change the color set. Here is a quick example... change the length of data to test.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/swevens/qzrnoxpn/)

```
var colorSet1 = ["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b"];
var colorSet2 = ["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"];

var colorSet = data.length%2 == 0 ? colorSet1 : colorSet2;
```

Code for above taken from D3 examples: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to color your slices.

```
color = d3.scale.ordinal()
               .domain([0,1,2,3])
               .range(["red", "green", "blue", "pink"]);;
color(0);//red
color(1);//green
color(2);//blue    
color(3);//pink
color(4);//red
color(5);//green
...so on //so the slice index can decide the color, using the scale.
```

**EDIT**

Make a function like this to ensure no adjacent colors are same.

Here `sliceNumber` is the index of slice in pie chart.
Here `maxSlices` is the maximum slices in the pie chart

```
function getMyColor(sliceNumber,maxSlices){
   if ((sliceNumber == maxSlices) && (color(sliceNumber) == color(maxSlices))){
       return color(sliceNumber + 1)
   } else {
       return color(sliceNumber)
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a solution only for rotating colors and not for avoiding adjacent same colors?  I was using this to rotate colors.

Comment: yes! you are right its for rotating colors. The only possibility of 2 adjacent colors getting same is when color(0) and color(n-1) are same for n slices.
Why not do a if check, from a function which returns color. if color(0) and color(n-1) are same then return color(n-2). check the edit block of my answer.